# Can't bind to 'routerLinkActiveOptions' since it isn't a known property

Tags: angular, typescript

Recently, I have started working with angular 8.Now on routing module when i started to configure it i was all good with it  except **ActiveTab** that i want to achieve with `routerLinkActiveOptions` on my `li` item in my **app.component.html** file

[image]

**App.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { UsersComponent } from './users/users.component';
import { ServersComponent } from './servers/servers.component';
import { UserComponent } from './users/user/user.component';
import { EditServerComponent } from './servers/edit-server/edit-server.component';
import { ServerComponent } from './servers/server/server.component';
import { ServersService } from './servers/servers.service';
import {Routes, RouterModule} from '@angular/router';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {path: '', component: HomeComponent},
  {path: 'users', component: UsersComponent},
  {path: 'servers', component: ServersComponent}

];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    UsersComponent,
    ServersComponent,
    UserComponent,
    EditServerComponent,
    ServerComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
  ],
  providers: [ServersService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
}
```

Comment: You cannot use these things on elements on which you don't have routerLink set since they are inputs defined by that directive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is due to typo, In your template (screenshot) you have written `routerlinkActive`, replace it with `routerLinkActive`.